# How to join 3 tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql

I have the following tables in the database:
(CUSTOMERS)
[CUSTOMER_ID] , [CUSTOMER_NAME]

(ORDERS)
[ORDER_ID]  ,  [ORDER_TYPE]

(CUSTOMERS_ORDERS)
[CUSTOMER_ID],  [ORDER_ID]

I'm trying to make the following query result:

[order_type],[Count(orders)], [count(distinct(customer_id))]

**What is the simplest way to implement this query.**

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet, and, if so, can you include your current code?  Stack Overflow tries to not be a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You should have pasted sample data and the output that you want. I'm going with fair assumptions -

```
SELECT O.ORDER_TYPE, COUNT(O.ORDER_ID), COUNT(DISTINCT CO.CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_ORDERS CO ON O.ORDER_ID = CO.ORDER_ID
GROUP BY O.ORDER_TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
  O.ORDER_TYPE, 
  COUNT(O.ORDER_ID), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CO.CUSTOMER_ID)
FROM ORDERS O
JOIN CUSTOMERS_ORDERS CO 
  ON O.ORDER_ID = CO.ORDER_ID
JOIN CUSTOMERS C
  ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = CO.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Next time when you ask a question, please post it with some sample data and expected result so that we can give you a proper solution.